# Joomla! what is the link to the new page I just created?

Tags: joomla, content-management-system

I have been tasked with updating a Joomla site. I have been working with existing pages for a while, but now I had to create a new page.

I just created a new page using Joomla. **But I can't find what the URL to that page is. Also, the pretty urls are enabled. But I don't know how to create a pretty url for the page I just created.**

I even tried adding the id to `/index.php?Itemid=` in the url and doesn't work.

Seems like something like this would be self-explanatory, but I have been looking around in the options and the menus and googling for the answer and I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: @SoboLan : this is actually a pretty straightforward question for Joomla, it may not be formally correct but it's easy to understand his problem and provide an answer.

Comment: it is overly complicated to do what I'm trying to do. Drupal is just not intuitive. basic tasks are overly complex and tedious. giving an article or page a pretty url should be a simple task. CAN ANYONE THAT MARKED MY QUESTION AS "not a real question" tell me in one sentence how to know the URL of the page you just created? NO. does drupal tell you right away what is the URL of the page you just created? NO. this IS a legitimate question.

Comment: `/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=37` then replace ID.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you need to attach an article to a category to view it.

You can assign the article to a category. After that open an article from that category and replace the text after the last "/" in url with the alias of your article.

You can also assign the article to a category that is linked to a menu item. that way you will be able to see the article link in the menu.

You may later remove the article from the category.

Comment: That exactly is the problem. Most pages are in the uncategorised category. The links look like this `domain.com/pretty-link` and I already tried `domain.com/my-link-that-doesnt-work` and I get a Not Found error. I have an alias, but I don't find how it's useful, it doesn't work

Comment: So is this new article added for the "Uncategorized" category?

If not, add to "uncategorized" category. Then esure the article is set to publish.

Then try domain.com/my-link-that-doesnt-work  .. it should work. By the way, Pretty-Link is nothing but the SEF (Search Engine Friendly) url.

Comment: your new page link is: index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=515 ; usually however you would create a menu item that points to the page to get a SEF url and get an Itemid assigned, which will allow you to customize which modules show up on the page besides the article.